# Getting a blank page when I save changes in wordpress plugin setting

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok I just created a plugin which works fine on the local server but not on the hosted server. 
The problem arises when I enter settings in the admin section and click on Save. I get a blank page/ browser stops.

It works fine in the local server though.

I understand it's something to do with my coding, but how can i tell which one is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the wp-config.php file and add/edit the line:

```
DEFINE('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you can try adding the line to your plugin:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

This SHOULD cause it to output the error(s) to the browser.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks Cale_b will try this one out. :)

Comment: I'll hang around in case that doesn't do it.

Comment: Is your whole WP install dead? Can you remove the plugin from the plugin directory?